# Why is My Constructor not Recognized?

Tags: c#

Constructor definition

```
public string LogLine(string line)
```

constructor usage

```
 LogLine ll = new LogLine(l);
```

error

> Logline does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Answer (score 6):

Constructors don't return values

Define the constructor like so

```
public class LogLine 
{
   public string Line { get; set; }
   public LogLine(string line) 
   {
      Line = line;
   }
}

// usage
var ll = new LogLine(l);
```

Answer (score 3):

your constructor has string as a return type.
the constructor doesn't have a return type

Answer (score 2):

Constructors don't return values, unlike yours which tries to return a string.

Additional note: Because you used access specifier for the constructor, drawing your attention to the fact that making it private will prohibit from that class being directly instantiated. It can be used in singleton design pattern.
However you can use static functions that can return class objects to instantiate a class with private constructors.